# Java is not finding the class

Tags: java, manifest

I have created a Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: DICOMValidate.menu
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/sl4j-api-1.6.4jar lib/sl4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar lib/dcm4che-audit-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-core-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-image-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-imageio-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-iod-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-net-2.0.2h.jar
```

When I attempt to run the file in Windows Command Prompt in directory: `C:\temp\workspace\DICOMVALIDATE>java -jar DICOMValidate.jar`, I get this error:

```
   View DICOM tags
    Enter DICOM File Path Name:
    C:/Ryan.dcm
    Enter Tag list:
    C:/testing.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dcm4che2/io/DicomInputStream
        at DicomValidator.viewDICOMTags.readDICOMObject(viewDICOMTags.java:40)
        at DicomValidator.menu.showMenu(menu.java:46)
        at DicomValidator.menu.main(menu.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        ... 3 more
```

This should be accessing DicomInputStream in the `dcm4che-core-2.0.25.jar`. I have no idea why it is not accessing that class as I have attempted this many times and still get the same result (despite me having made sure spelling and everything is correct). Can someone please help me figure out why this .jar is not getting accessed?

UPDATE:
 I have made all the changes you recommended but I am still getting hit with the same error:

```
Please Enter:
1 to View DICOM Tags
2 to Add DICOM Tags
3 to Edit DICOM Tags
4 to exit
1
View DICOM tags
Enter DICOM File Path Name:
IM-0009-0001.dcm
Enter Tag list:
tags.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dcm4che2/io/DicomInputStream
        at DicomValidator.viewDICOMTags.readDICOMObject(viewDICOMTags.java:40)
        at DicomValidator.menu.showMenu(menu.java:45)
        at DicomValidator.menu.main(menu.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dcm4che2.io.DicomInputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        ... 3 more
```

Can someone please help me figure out why it is not recognizing DicomInputStream?????

Comment: 1. What's the command line you use to run the file? 2. Which directory are you in when you run the command? 3. Which directory is `lib\sl4j-api-1.6.4.jar` in?

Comment: Hold on, I will update my question with that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your MANIFEST.MF.

First, you have several library names that are incorrect, as pointed by ctrueden.

Second, your MANIFEST.MF must not have any line longer than 72 bytes ([See ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Notes_on_Manifest_and_Signature_Files)).

So all in all, your MANIFEST.MF should be the following (tested locally):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: DICOMValidate.menu
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar lib/slf4j
 -api-1.6.4.jar lib/dcm4che-audit-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-core-2.0.25.j
 ar lib/dcm4che-image-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-imageio-2.0.25.jar lib/dc
 m4che-iod-2.0.25.jar lib/dcm4che-net-2.0.25.jar
```

Finally, as recommended by others, you should really use Maven. Here's the POM file as it should be to build the jar that you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>tmp2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dcm4che</id>
            <url>http://www.dcm4che.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-audit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-image</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-iod</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dcm4che</groupId>
            <artifactId>dcm4che-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>DICOMValidate.menu</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is still generating the same exception even after I have made changes (with both examples you gave me)..

Comment: Those exceptions are present because of the issue underlined by ctruden. Fix those, then make sure to have your MANIFEST.MF comply to this 72-bytes rule.

Comment: Are there any other recommendations?

Comment: I appreciate the help but any more info you can recommend would be very useful for me.

Comment: As requested, here's the MANIFEST.MF that you should have. Also, I added the pom.xml file that you should use to have Maven work instead of you, reducing the number of issues on your side. Your last issue was actually that you had written `lib/dcm4che-net-2.0.2h.jar` instead of `lib/dcm4che-net-2.0.25.jar`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a typo in your `Class-Path` entry. You have `lib/slfj-api-1.6.4jar` but it should be `lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar`. You also specify `lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar` but at least one dependency needs `log4j-1.2.17.jar`. The error message "The archive: /DICOMVALIDATE/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist" was a nice hint there.

In general, make sure you have all needed JAR files, and their dependencies, etc., on the classpath. Otherwise, you may get `ClassNotFoundException` even when the class itself is present but a dependency is not. I would heartily recommend using a build system with dependency management skills, such as Maven or Gradle, to keep all your ducks in a row more easily. Maven generates a manifest for you, so that you do not need to do it by hand.

Comment: It should probably be `lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar` (note the missing `f`). SLF4J is a widely used logging facade library.

Comment: Thanks, I will look forward to using Maven in the future. I have already built the project and am just looking to wrap it up...

Comment: And also `lib/sl4fj-log4j12-1.6.4.jar` instead of `lib/sl4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar`.

Comment: I will give it a go. But when I run this, it complains about not finding a different class in another .jar file.

Comment: @ryekayo It may be faster to switch your build system over to Maven (while learning it!) than to debug all the problems caused by using manifests by hand... ;-)

Comment: Understood. I will look into this in the meantime

Comment: I know you mentioned using Maven or Gradle. But I am very rusty with using Maven. Is there anything else you would recommend? I have made all the necessary changes and am still getting hit with the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The class will not be on the classpath, print the following expression from your program:

```
((URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).getURLs();
```

and it will print the classpath.

Comment: I am sorry but where in my program would i print that in. the main class?

Comment: I get this: The archive: /DICOMVALIDATE/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

Comment: I cant delete it out of Eclipse, I have deleted it in WIndows since I am not using that jar file

Comment: It keeps saying it is out of synch

Comment: Please help! I can't get rid of the .jar that it is referring to. That jar should not be in lib and I can't delete it in eclipse!